# How can I find out which provider versions are provided with a particular version of airflow?

Tags: airflow

How do I know which version of [airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.emr](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/_api/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/operators/emr/index.html) is available on a particular version of airflow?

One thing I've tried is to run the docker image for a particular version of airflow and then search in the image for the operators, but I don't know where in the image I should look.

I assumed I'd find something in site-packages, but it wasn't to be:

```bash
docker run -it \
  --entrypoint /bin/bash apache/airflow:2.7.3 \
  -c "ls -l /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages"
```

which returns

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  119 Nov  1 14:45 README.txt
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov  1 14:45 _distutils_hack
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  152 Nov  1 14:45 distutils-precedence.pth
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Nov  1 14:45 pip
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov  1 14:45 pip-23.0.1.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Nov  1 14:45 pkg_resources
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Nov  1 14:45 setuptools
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov  1 14:45 setuptools-57.5.0.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Nov  1 14:45 wheel
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov  1 14:45 wheel-0.41.3.dist-info
```

There's no clue there as to where provider code might reside.

I suppose my wider question is "Where do the airflow providers reside in the airflow image?" but right now I'd just like to know specifically about `airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.emr`. I know the operators are there:

```bash
docker run -it \
  --entrypoint /bin/bash apache/airflow:2.7.3 \
  -c "python -c 'from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.emr import EmrServerlessStartJobOperator;print(EmrServerlessStartJobOperator)'"
<class 'airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.emr.EmrServerlessStartJobOperator'>
```

but how do I know which version that is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realised I can get the information I need from pip. doh.

```bash
> docker run -it \
  --entrypoint /bin/bash apache/airflow:2.7.3 \
  -c "pip freeze" | grep amazon
apache-airflow-providers-amazon==8.10.0
```